# Powershell Regex Pattern for EDI

Tags: regex, powershell, edi

New to Powershell/Regex/EDI. Please no comments on why this shouldn't be done with regular expressions for EDI, I've seen the warnings, but have no choice.

What I need is most likely basic, but I need some help. I have to find all instances of a segment, and retrieve a specific element value from it. The text being searched will be read as one long string, with no CR/LF/etc.

Example data:

```
~SV1*HC:V2020*35*UN*1***1~DTP*472*D8*20120807~REF*6R*
~SV1*HC:V2100:LT*28.98*UN*1***1~DTP*472*D8*20120807~REF*6R*
~SV1*HC:92014*165*UN*1***1~DTP*472*D8*20120716~REF*6R*
```

I'm using the following command on another segment and it works just like i want, but it doesn't have to account for non-word characters either:

```
Select-String -pattern '~svd\*\w+\*(\d+|\d+\.\d+)\*' -input $string -AllMatches | %{$_.Matches} | %{$_.Groups[1]} | %{$_.Value}
```

Ideally, I would like to find an instance of "~SV1*", skip to the next asterisk, then read everything through the next asterisk. That way it doesn't matter what letter/number/character is in there, it skips it. In the data example above, I would want a return of 35, 28.98, 165. If not, then I can work with what I have, but matching on combinations of word/non-word characters is throwing me, since I don't know what order they may exist in. Everything else I've played with has continued on pulling the rest of the string, and not stopping properly.

If I can get it to do this, I'd be very happy:

```
~SV1*<skip this>*<get this>*<skip to next SV1>~SV1*<skip this>*<get this>*<skip to next SV1>
```

Lastly, the data being pulled is a money field, so it may or may not have a decimal present. If there is a cleaner way than (\d+|\d+.\d+), I'm all for it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a pattern like this:

```
 ~sv\d\*[^*]*\*([^*]*)\*
```

Comment: This actually worked better for my situation, as I could plug in segment and get the results I wanted, adjusting asterisks for the elements I wanted to skip. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

A starting point, but you need to test it:

```
Select-String -pattern '(?<=~sv\d\*.*\*)(\d*\.?\d+)(?=\*un)' -input $string -AllMatches | %{$_.Matches} | % {$_.Groups[1]} | %{$_.Value}
```

Using your example data returns 35, 28.98, 165.

Comment: Initial tests look good. I'll reply later today or Monday once I've put it through the paces. Runing a sum on all these values now gets the expected result, before I was missing matches and getting lower numbers. If you don't mind, can you give me a quick breakdown of exactly why this works? Especially the (?=\*un). Thanks!

Comment: @DavidJones (?<=...) and (?=...) are lookbehind and lookahead assertions. Here http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html you can find a good explanation

Comment: Good resource, lots of good info there. Your example also helped me find some other things I had done wrong, thanks again!